# Will an expired CommandTimeout terminate pending "deadlocks"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, deadlock

When the [`CommandTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) of an SQL command expires, is it guaranteed to immediately terminate the command?

That is, will a CommandTimeout terminate the command while the executing SQL is in a "deadlocked" state in the database?

The "deadlock" in this case might actually be a livelock and undetectable from SQL Server; hence the quotes. In code, failure of the command will result in closing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently came across a similar question. The deadlock may stay put regardless of your C# code throwing the **CommandTimeout** exception. I believe there is an ***cancellation event signal*** sent to the DB from your C# application layer that the command is timing out and that the query should be Aborted but **it is up to the DB to clear-up the deadlock**. That can take time depending on how many transactions have to be rolled back etc. (You can always try to kill the deadlocked SPID but I would be very careful since that may cause some issues without giving you any error logs to figure out what went wrong.)

You may consider using  `SET XACT_ABORT ON` if you are using transactions and have frequent timeouts.

I think the question is why is it deadlocked? You can use `exec SP_WHO2` to see what is being locked or run SQL Profiler / Trace to see the culprit.